# Cannot resolve promise in output event for component used in router

Tags: angular, routes, promise

I have a component that's meant to be used in another component that wraps it for the route. This component has an output event that triggers navigation back to the parent route:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <button (click)="back($event)">Back</button>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Output() helloBack = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  back($event) {
    this.router.navigate(['./'], { relativeTo: this.route.parent })
      .then(() => {
        this.helloBack.emit($event);
      });
  }
}
```

Next, I create the wrapper component to use in the route:

```
@Component({
  template: `
  <hello (helloBack)="onBack()">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </hello>
  `
})
export class HelloRouteComponent {
  onBack() {
    console.log('back!!!');
  }
}
```

Finally, I load this in the routing module:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'hello',
    component: HelloRouteComponent
  }
])
```

When I go to the `/hello` route the `HelloRouteComponent` loads fine. When I click the back button, it navigates to the parent route, *but* it doesn't log anything to the console after successfully navigating there.

Why isn't the promise resolving? What am I missing for this to work?

**Demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rewax8?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is because by the time `router.navigate()` is resolved, and `helloBack.emit()` is invoked, the binding `<hello (helloBack)="onBack()">` does not exist anymore since `HelloComponent` is already detached.

You may want to use a shared service that declares a `Subject<T>` field (a natural replacement for `@Output` event/`EventEmitter`). And use that subject instead. Does it make sense?

---

The service can look as the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class HelloContextService {

    private _helloBackSubject = new Subject<any>();
    $helloBack: Observable<any>;

    constructor() {
        this.$helloBack = this._helloBackSubject.asObservable();
    }

    emitHelloBack(payload: any): void {
        this._helloBackSubject.next(payload);
    }
}
```

You'll need to inject it into both of your components. `HelloComponent` can then call `this.emitHelloBack($event)`, and the other component can subscribe to the `$helloBack` observable.

**HelloComponent**:

```
export class HelloComponent {

    constructor(private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private helloContextService: HelloContextService) {
    }

    back($event) {
        this.router.navigate(['./'], { relativeTo: this.route.parent })
            .then(() => {
                this.helloContextService.emitHelloBack($event);
            });
    }
}
```

The other component:

```
export class HelloRouteComponent  {
    constructor(private helloContextService: HelloContextService) {
        this.helloContextService
            .$helloBack
            .subscribe(payload => {
                // ...
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Can you demonstrate how this service would work?

Comment: I see... Not sure this will work for my use case, because the route component is created by the user that consumes my component, and I have no control over that, and I don't want the user to have to inject a service, and so on.

Comment: @elclanrs I don't think I understand why you don't want to inject a service -- that's one of a few standard mechanisms for component communication. If you don't want to go that route, you will need to fight the detachment of your `<hello>` component on navigation -- which I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

In your application you exposed a event emitter by defining `@Output` type variable and you are catching that in child compoenent. So all looks good.

I think the problem might be `this.router.navigate` is not getting called or `onBack(event: EditEvent)` you did not passed parameter to the called function.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <button (click)="back($event)">Back</button>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Output() helloBack = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  back($event) {
    this.helloBack.emit({status: 'gone back'});
    this.router.navigate(['./'], { relativeTo: this.route.parent })
      .then(() => {
        this.helloBack.emit($event);

      });
  }
}
```

add parameter to the onBack method

```
@Component({
  template: `
  <hello (helloBack)="onBack()">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </hello>
  `
})
export class HelloRouteComponent {

  onBack(event: EditEvent) {
    console.log('back!!!');
  }
}
Finally, I load this in the routing module:

RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'hello',
    component: HelloRouteComponent
  }
])
```

I think little bit of debugging will resolve your problem.